# nmake Won't Work - Qt

Tags: c++, qt, deployment

I am trying to deploy my project(built with Qt Creator) into a single, static executable(Windows). I am having trouble doing this, even though I feel like I am following the Qt tutorial exactly.

The tutorial I am following: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html

First, I open the Qt Command Promt, and enter 'configure -static'.
Just to ensure I am doing EVERYTHING correct, I am even showing the command prompt I am using.

[image]

I go through the 'configure' steps, and this is my output.

After entering the 'configure -static' command, I get this as the output. (put on Pastie to keep this clean).

http://pastie.org/3580144

I then enter 'nmake sub-src', and get this as the output:

```
C:\Qt\4.8.0>nmake sub-src

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    cd ..\..\src\tools\bootstrap\ && c:\Qt\4.8.0\bin\qmake.exe \src\tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.pro -o Makefile
Cannot find file: \src\tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.pro.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2' Stop.

C:\Qt\4.8.0>
```

I get this same output even if I just command 'nmake'. I have the Qt SDK installed, and I have no idea what to do at this point as I've Googled everything. Thanks for any help, Hetelek.

Comment: It's saying it can't find the file `\src\tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.pro` - does that file actually exist (and is it where nmake thinks it is)?

Comment: Yes, it does exists.

http://i.imgur.com/xr8pn.png

Comment: I sent this before but take a look at this: http://www.qtforum.org/article/34242/my-guide-for-using-qt-shared-libraries-based-on-qt-open-source-library-with-vc-compiler-in-windows.html Also, I built my lib in visual studio (shared lib) and it worked when straight away. Try that aproach and and look at what I did, which should be pretty similar. Things might be compiled or made with different tools that arent compatible or something. getting qt to run on vs is not too hard http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Also, we have used nmake in all the examples, but if you use MinGW you must use mingw32-make instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's that leading slash on the file path - it makes the file path "absolute."  SO nmake is looking for the file:

`C:\src\tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.pro`

but your file is actually saved as:

`C:\Qt\4.8.0\src\tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.pro`

Now, I'm not sure how to configure nmake to use the right path, but that's your problem right there.  And if all else fails, you can always move your src folder to the root of your C drive so it's where nmake expects it to be.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think this is one of the steps to getting it to work, but unfortunately more errors were thrown:

http://pastie.org/3582025

Comment: @hetelek - It looks like you're missing the DirectShow/Direct3D SDK and perl.  Install those and try again.  And if that still won't do it, try posting another question, and maybe someone more familiar with the process can help you out.

Comment: I had many of the same errors as @hetelek, but I do have the Windows SDK installed. It turned out I just needed to set the QTDIR environment variable.